# How do you print the Integration Test ( maven failsafe ) in the console?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I wonder what do I need to do , in order for me to see the Test Runs in the console output? ( like real-time ?)

All I see is this during test execution.

```
[INFO] ------------------< com.testframework:testframework >-------------------
[INFO] Building Automation UI Test Framework 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ testframework ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/geronimo.sanpascual/Documents/Projects/ctc/autoTests/automation_ui_testframework/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ testframework ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 10 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ testframework ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 76 source files to /Users/geronimo.sanpascual/Documents/Projects/ctc/autoTests/automation_ui_testframework/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ testframework ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ testframework ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/geronimo.sanpascual/Documents/Projects/ctc/autoTests/automation_ui_testframework/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ testframework ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ testframework ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/geronimo.sanpascual/Documents/Projects/ctc/autoTests/automation_ui_testframework/target/testframework-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M4:integration-test (default) @ testframework ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
```

And then after the build is done - then only I see the failures if there are any.

Essentially my goal is - to see from the console in real time which "test" is being executed.

Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

Here's the POM structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>testframework</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Automation UI Test Framework</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven-download-plugin.version>1.3.0</maven-download-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire.version>3.0.0-M4</maven-surefire.version>
        <logback-classic.version>1.2.3</logback-classic.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <owner.version>1.0.8</owner.version>
        <testng.version>6.14.3</testng.version>
        <webdrivermanager.version>3.7.1</webdrivermanager.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.10</lombok.version>
        <hamcrest-all.version>1.3</hamcrest-all.version>
        <selenium-java.version>3.6.0</selenium-java.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <common-io.version>2.6</common-io.version>
        <cucumber.version>5.1.0</cucumber.version>
        <cucumber-html.version>0.2.7</cucumber-html.version>
        <cucumber-jvm-deps.version>1.0.6</cucumber-jvm-deps.version>
        <cluecumber-report.version>2.3.1</cluecumber-report.version>
        <gherkin.version>5.1.0</gherkin.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.6</gson.version>
        <skipStaticAnalysis>false</skipStaticAnalysis>
        <rest_assured.version>4.2.0</rest_assured.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
       <!--Java core-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback-classic.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest-all.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Cucumber Selenium requirements-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber-html.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>${gherkin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
            <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cluecumber-report.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Properties file mapper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aeonbits.owner</groupId>
            <artifactId>owner</artifactId>
            <version>${owner.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Auto WebDriver manager/downloader-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdrivermanager.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--HTTP Calls-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest_assured.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Dependency Injection : Cucumber State Transfer-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--JUnit Parallel Test Run Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <!-- excluding testNG runner : Parallel Test collision issue due to
                                 Cucumber scenario implementation.-->
                                <exclude>**/DeveloperTools.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <parallel>classesAndMethods</parallel>
                            <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                            <perCoreThreadCount>false</perCoreThreadCount>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.trivago.rta</groupId>
                <artifactId>cluecumber-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cluecumber-report.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ALL BANNERS TEST REPORT</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>reporting</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceJsonReportDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report/</sourceJsonReportDirectory>
                            <generatedHtmlReportDirectory>test-report/all-cluecumber-reports</generatedHtmlReportDirectory>
                            <expandBeforeAfterHooks>true</expandBeforeAfterHooks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${skipStaticAnalysis}</skip>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <configLocation>build_config/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <propertyExpansion>basedir=${project.basedir}</propertyExpansion>
                    <violationSeverity>info</violationSeverity>
                    <includeTestSourceDirectory>true</includeTestSourceDirectory>
                    <sourceDirectories>
                        <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
                    </sourceDirectories>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: How have you called Maven?

Comment: @khmarbaise mvn clean verify

Comment: If you as given you see executing test class by test class ? I have to admin that I don't understand your question?